# Logo not showing on some store views magento

Tags: php, magento, template-engine

I have one website with multiple store views for each language.
For some reason the logo is not showing on some store views.

On the store views that the logo is showing, the expected path appears in the href of the logo, namely:

```
 base_url/skin/frontend/default/myTheme/images/logo.png
```

Whereas on the store views that have a the broken link to the logo, for some reason it is not finding it in the theme directory and it is reverting back to the base directory as follows:

```
 base_url/skin/frontend/base/defualt/images/logo.png
```

I'm not sure where I may have gone wrong. And why the logo would appear on one view and not the other. The views that are displaying the logo were set a while back, I simply added new views at this point in time.

**Additional info**

1. The new store views were created under System > Manage Stores
2. They were given the code name mytheme_languagename e.g. mytheme_french
3. I have one url, the store views are simply to translate the store for regional users
4. I have the correct settings under System > Configuration > Design > template
5. I have set design changes under System > Design on at least one of the views, but the results are always the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about your design settings?

```
I have the correct settings under System > Configuration > Design > template
```

The logo is a skin setting, so you should have "myTheme" set for skin or for default on all store views!

This is because when it correctly finds an image, your URL is

```
 base_url/skin/frontend/default/**myTheme**/images/logo.png
```

Comment: Yes, this is set correctly Default Config, Design > skin = mytheme and Design > Default = mytheme I am completely stumped.

Comment: @shnozolla Can you attach a picture of your config setting? Also, here you write lowercase "mytheme" while in the URL you said "myTheme" - casing error maybe?

Comment: sorry about that, I was using an arbitrary name, the actual theme name is: "winestore" all lower case, and here is a link to the screenshot of the default config settings. awesomescreenshot.com/0a7qltq49 Thanks.

Comment: @shnozolla And when you switch to a store view on the same settings page, there is winestore indicated there as well (or at least a fallback to default which is winestore)?
If so, then I agree with you that this is very strange.
Also another thing I noted in your screenshot it says logo.gif while in your question you wrote something of logo.png - could this be an issue that you specified different endings in different store views?

Comment: oh man after all that, it was an issue with logo.png vs. logo.gif, it is working nicely now, i'm just not sure how i got different results on separate store views if logo was set to logo.gif for ALL store views. (How would it appear on some store views and not others??) Anyhow, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

1. First remove all the design changes from System > Configuration >
   Design and System->Design.
2. Then apply the design changes for each store view only from System->Design.
3. Make sure what your Logo is named, Logo.gif or Logo.png